# Dynamic `modifies` clause in while loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, dafny

The `modifies` clause in while loops is evaluated only once, when entering the loop for the first time. For example, if I have a sequence of objects and I grow it but also modify the new elements that I created in previous iterations, Dafny won't accept it:

```
class Foo {
  var x: int;

  constructor()
  {
    x := 0;
  }
}

method main(n: nat)
  requires n > 0
{
  var first := new Foo();
  var arr: seq<Foo> := [first];
  var i := 1;
  while i < n
    modifies set x | x in arr
    invariant 0 <= i <= n
    invariant |arr| == i
  {
    arr[i-1].x := i;
    var next := new Foo();
    arr := arr + [next];
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

I have tried using recursion and it works, but I want to use a while loop for illustration purposes. Is there any other way to overcome this issue? Is there some kind of "dynamic" `modifies` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fresh`,

```
method main(n: nat)
  requires n > 0 
{
  var first := new Foo();
  var arr: seq<Foo> := [first];
  var i := 1;

  while i < n 
    invariant 0 <= i <= n
    invariant |arr| == i
    invariant fresh(set x | x in arr)
  {
    arr[i-1].x := i;
    var next := new Foo();
    arr := arr + [next];
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

The `fresh(X)` predicate means that the objects in the set X were allocated since the beginning of the current method. You're always allowed to modify fresh objects, even when they weren't declared in the method's `modifies` clause. (In fact, it's not even possible for a `fresh` object to be in the `modifies` clause, since by definition, the object wasn't allocated at the point in time the `modifies` clause is evaluated.)

Note though that `fresh` means "fresh since the start of the current *method*", not current while loop, and I've removed your while loop's `modifies` clause entirely in this fixed snippet. I'm not sure if it's possible to make your original `modifies` clauses work or not - but you should be able to get by with only method-level `modifies` clauses and while-loop-level `invariant` clauses.

(In this case, there is no explicit method-level `modifies` clause; thus the `modifies` clause is implicitly the empty set.)